# Unable to make symlinks effectively with target files of the same names

Tags: unix, ln

I have a list of dotFiles at my workarea. For example, .bashrc and .vimrc.

I want to make a symlinks from them to my Home such that their names are the same as in my workarea -folder.

**My attempt in pseudo-code**

```
ln workarea/.[a-zA-Z] ~/.*
```

The problem is to have a bijection from [a-zA-Z] to the files which occur in my Home.

**How can you make symlinks with the target files of same name as the original files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'man ln' says:

> ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)

So you need to do something like:

$ `ln -s workarea/.* ~/`

Answer (score 1):

The possible uses of `ln` to create symbolic link(s) are:

```
ln -s <source-file> [<target-file]>
ln -s <source-file> ... <target-dir>
```

When you type

```
ln -s workarea/.[a-zA-Z]* ~/.*
```

(I think you were missing a `*`) the shell will expand out `workarea/.[a-zA-Z]` **and** `~/.*`, so (presuming that the your HOME directory contains the files `.abc` and `.def`) you would end up with

```
ln -s workarea/.bash_profile workarea/.bashrc ~/.abc ~/.def
```

which fits neither usage of `ln`.

To use the second usage of `ln`, you would use:

```
ln -s workarea/.[a-zA-Z]* ~/.
```